# Visual studio 2017 Publish web project to folder fails

Tags: visual-studio-2017, roslyn

The following errors pop in the log when publishing web project to folder.

```
....
Publishing folder /...
Publishing folder bin...
Publishing folder bin/es...
Publishing folder bin/roslyn...
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/System.IO.FileSystem.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\System.IO.FileSystem.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/System.ValueTuple.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\System.ValueTuple.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Unable to add 'bin/roslyn/VBCSCompiler.exe' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Publishing folder bin/zh...
...
Publishing folder Views/WFDefs...
Publish failed. Target file://machine/d$/PATH.
```

If i publish using web publish it works, but the real target doesn't support web publishing.

Note: VBCSCompiler is not running.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my application with Visual Studio community 2017. In my case the solution was simple, I only deleted all the files inside the directory bin (C:\Projects\DotNet\ApplicationName\bin) and after I recompiled the application.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. As your question came up in Google but no answer, I thought I'd add to it.

I found [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) helped me a bunch.

Open sysinternals and go to Find -> Find Handle or DLL... or (Ctrl + F) and search the file that's being held open. In my case "System.IO.FileSystem.dll"

The search results showed two instances of MSBuild and one VBCSCompiler was hanging onto the files. Worst case, I just killed the process tree, built the project and all was well again.

Related answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you try to publish asp.net web app in Azure and getting above error then try to **UPDATE the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package to V1.0.7 or later**. Initially, in your application, there will be Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform version 1.0.5 then *uninstall and then install the latest version V 1.0.7 or later of it*. Clean your solution and build. Now you will be able to publish your web app in Azure using **Visual Studio 2017.**